# How to push to History in React Router Dom v6

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I tried many times but couldn't upgrade my code to make `push.history` work properly.

here is my old code with react-router-dom v5:

This code perfectly works in the previous version but as I upgraded to v6 I don't know what will be the replacement of `withRouter` and `push.history` in the new version.

```
import React from 'react'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import TextFieldGroup from '../common/TextFieldGroup'
import TextAreaFieldGroup from '../common/TextAreaFieldGroup'
import SelectListGroup from '../common/SelectListGroup'
import InputGroup from '../common/InputGroup'
import { createProfile } from '../../actions/profileActions'

class CreateProfile extends React.Component{
    constructor( props ) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            displaySocialInputs: false,
            handle: '',
            company: '',
            website: '',
            location: '',
            status: '',
            skills: '',
            githubusername: '',
            bio: '',
            twitter: '',
            facebook: '',
            linkedin: '',
            youtube: '',
            instagram: '',
            errors:{}
        }


        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)

    }

    UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ) {
        if ( nextProps.errors ) {
            this.setState(()=>({ errors: nextProps.errors }))
        }
    }
    onSubmit( e ){
        e.preventDefault()
        
        const profileData = {
            handle: this.state.handle,
            company: this.state.company,
            website: this.state.website,
            location: this.state.location,
            status: this.state.status,
            skills: this.state.skills,
            githubusername: this.state.githubusername,
            bio: this.state.bio,
            twitter: this.state.twitter,
            facebook: this.state.facebook,
            linkedin: this.state.linkedin,
            youtube: this.state.youtube,
            instagram: this.state.instagram,
        }

        this.props.createProfile( profileData , this.props.history )
    }

    onChange( e ) {
        e.persist()
        this.setState(()=>({ [ e.target.name ]: e.target.value }))
    }

    render(){

        const options = [
            { label: 'وضعیت حرفه ای خود را انتخاب فرمایید *' , value : 0 },
            { label: 'برنامه نویس' , value : 'برنامه نویس' },
            { label: 'برنامه نویس مبتدی' , value : 'برنامه نویس مبتدی' },
            { label: 'برنامه نویس با تجربه' , value : 'برنامه نویس با تجربه' },
            { label: 'مدیر' , value : 'مدیر' },
            { label: 'درحال یادگیری' , value : 'درحال یادگیری' },
            { label: 'مدرس' , value : 'مدرس' },
            { label: 'دانشجو' , value : 'دانشجو' },
            { label: 'سایر' , value : 'سایر' }

        ]

        const { errors , displaySocialInputs } = this.state
        let socialInputes

        if ( displaySocialInputs ) {
            socialInputes = (
                    <div>
                        <InputGroup 
                            placeholder="آدرس شبکه توئیتر"
                            name="twitter"
                            icon="fab fa-twitter"
                            value={this.state.twitter}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            error={errors.twitter}
                        />


                        <InputGroup 
                            placeholder="آدرس شبکه فیسبوک"
                            name="facebook"
                            icon="fab fa-facebook"
                            value={this.state.facebook}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            error={errors.facebook}
                        />

                        <InputGroup 
                            placeholder="آدرس شبکه لینکدن"
                            name="linkedin"
                            icon="fab fa-linkedin"
                            value={this.state.linkedin}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            error={errors.linkedin}
                        />


                        <InputGroup 
                            placeholder="آدرس شبکه یوتیوب"
                            name="youtube"
                            icon="fab fa-youtube"
                            value={this.state.youtube}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            error={errors.youtube}
                        />


                        <InputGroup 
                            placeholder="آدرس شبکه اینستاگرم"
                            name="instagram"
                            icon="fab fa-instagram"
                            value={this.state.instagram}
                            onChange={this.onChange}
                            error={errors.instagram}
                        />

                    </div>
            )
        }

        return (
            <div className="create-profile">
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                            <h1 className="display-4 text-center">ساخت پروفایل شما</h1>
                            <p className="lead text-center">یک معرفی خوب وصعت کارتان را بیشتر می کند</p>
                            <small className="d-block bp-3 text-right">فیلدهای ستاره دار * اجباری می باشند</small>
                            <form onSubmit={ this.onSubmit }>

                                <TextFieldGroup 
                                    placeholder="هندلر پروفایل *"
                                    name="handle"
                                    value={this.state.handle}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.handle}
                                    info="منظور از handle داشتن URL اختصاصی پروفایل شماست"
                                />


                                <SelectListGroup 
                                    placeholder="وضعیت"
                                    name="status"
                                    value={this.state.status}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.status}
                                    options={options}
                                    info="تصویری از وضعیت کنونی شما"
                                />

                                <TextFieldGroup 
                                    placeholder="شرکت"
                                    name="company"
                                    value={this.state.company}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.company}
                                    info="شرکت خودتان یا جایی که در آنجا مشغول به کار هستید"
                                />

                                <TextFieldGroup 
                                    placeholder="وب سایت"
                                    name="website"
                                    value={this.state.website}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.website}
                                    info="وب سایت خودتان یا جاییکه کار می کنید"
                                />

                                <TextFieldGroup 
                                    placeholder="محل"
                                    name="location"
                                    value={this.state.location}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.location}
                                    info="شهر یا استان و شهر"
                                />

                                <TextFieldGroup 
                                    placeholder="مهارت ها *"
                                    name="skills"
                                    value={this.state.skills}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.skills}
                                    info="برای جدا سازی عبارت ها از کاما استفاده کنید html, css, js, php"
                                />


                                <TextFieldGroup 
                                    placeholder="نام کاربری شما در گیت هاب"
                                    name="githubusername"
                                    value={this.state.githubusername}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.githubusername}
                                    info="برای ایجاد ارتباط و دسترسی به مخازن عمومی شما لطفا نام کاربری خودتان را وارد فرمایید"
                                />

                                <TextAreaFieldGroup 
                                    placeholder="مختصری از خودتان"
                                    name="bio"
                                    value={this.state.bio}
                                    onChange={this.onChange}
                                    error={errors.bio}
                                    info="لطفا توضیح مختصری از خودتان برای علاقمندان خودتان بنویسد"
                                />

                                <div className="mb-3 text-right">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"                                        
                                        className="btn btn-light" onClick={ () => {
                                        this.setState(( prevState)=>({ displaySocialInputs: !prevState.displaySocialInputs }))
                                    }}>
                                                اضافه کردن کانکشن در مدیا
                                    </button>
                                    <span className="text-muted">اختیاری میباشد</span>
                                </div>
                                        { socialInputes }
                                        <input type="submit" value="ثبت" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

CreateProfile.propTypes = {
    profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    errors: PropTypes.object.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = ( state ) => {
    return {
        profile: state.profile,
        errors: state.errors
    }
}

export default connect( mapStateToProps , { createProfile })( withRouter( CreateProfile ) )
```

My action files

```
export const createProfile = ( profileData , history ) => ( dispatch ) => {
  axios.post( '/api/profile' , profileData )
  .then(( result ) =>{
    history.push('/dashboard') 
  }).catch(( errors )=> {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_ERRORS,
      payload: errors.response.data
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: this can help you maybe: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/faq#what-happened-to-withrouter-i-need-it

Answer (score 5):

After `react-router-dom` version 6 `push.history` has changed.

`Push.history('/dashboard')` --> `navigate('/dashboard')`

Example of using the `usenavigate` hook:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function Invoices() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  return (
    <div>
      <NewInvoiceForm
        onSubmit={async (event) => {
          let newInvoice = await createInvoice(
            event.target
          );
          navigate(`/invoices/${newInvoice.id}`);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`useNavigate` usage in react-router v6

```js
import {useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/home')
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Answer (score 0):

The `useNavigate` hook returns a function that lets you navigate programmatically, for example after a form is submitted. If using `replace: true`, the navigation will replace the current entry in the history stack instead of adding a new one.

The navigate function has two signatures:

- Either pass a To value (same type as `<Link to>`) with an optional second `{ replace, state }` arg or
- Pass the delta you want to go in the history stack. For example, `navigate(-1)` is equivalent to hitting the back button.

You can follow this example:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

function exampleNavigation() {
  let navigate = useNavigate();
  navigate('/your_url');
}
```